# I want to open every item within website for scraping using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to open a website for scraping i.e after opening a new tab for a product it should scrape and then return to original tab followed by other products.
I think the issue is with Xpath and i have use xpath "//a[contains(@class,'prdLink')]"

Here i have used xpath method but somehow it is not opening the pages

```
  chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/ptiwar34/Documents/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
    
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get("https://www.besse.com/pages/products-specialties/productsbyspecialty/allspecialties")
            my_hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'prdLink')]")))]
            windows_before  = driver.current_window_handle 
            for my_href in my_hrefs:
                driver.execute_script("window.open('" + my_href +"');")
                WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2)) 
                windows_after = driver.window_handles
                new_window = [x for x in windows_after if x != windows_before][0] 
                driver.switch_to.window(new_window) 
                time.sleep(3) 
                print(driver.title) 
                driver.close() 
                driver.switch_to.window(windows_before) 
        except TimeoutException:
            print("No more pages")
            break
    driver.quit()
```

It does not open even a single item and output is no more pages

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is correct, the problem is that those links are not visible. You would need to extend all sections (and you would need to use scrolling down to achieve that).

Much faster in this case would be to parse the page source rather then use selenium here.

```py
from lxml import etree

driver.get("https://www.besse.com/pages/products-specialties/productsbyspecialty/allspecialties")

root = etree.HTML(driver.page_source)

# there is @href!='' in xpath because some hrefs contains empty string
my_hrefs = root.xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'prdLink') and @href!='']/@href")
for my_href in my_hrefs:
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: It throws error XPathEvalError: Unregistered function

Comment: the only function that xpath uses is `contains`. Could you send me xpath string that you're using and xpath version?